# Onclick changing content on <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, customization

Is there a way I can make the on the right appear one at a time? And show by sliding?

Here's the code I'm using to call the

```
<button onClick="div1()">Try it</button>
<button onClick="div2()">Try it</button>
<button onClick="div3()">Try it</button>
```

Here is the script I am using

```
<script>
function div1() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function div2() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV2');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function div3() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV3');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to make my site look like this

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.I think you need to be more descriptive to get an answer here. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `.slideToggle()` could be used to show by sliding

Comment: where do i put the .slideToggle()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating a function where you send the div number ( 1 , 2 , 3 ...) you can slide the concerned div and hide all the others .

Try the bellow snippet : ( using jquery ) ,

```js
function toggleDiv(divNum) {
    
    $("#close").hide();
    $(".slide").animate({right:'-200'},350);
    if($("#div"+divNum)) {
        
        $("#div"+divNum).animate({right:'0'},350,function(){$("#close").show();});
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#close").on("click",function(e){
      $(".slide").animate({right:'-200'},350);
      $(this).hide()
   })

})
```

```css
.slide {
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  right:-200px;
  top:0;
  background:#d2d2d2;
}

#close {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:10px;
  z-index:10;
  display:none;
}

#right-content {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="toggleDiv(1)">Try it 1</button>
<button onClick="toggleDiv(2)">Try it 2</button>
<button onClick="toggleDiv(3)">Try it 3</button>

<div id="right-content">
  <div id="close">X</div>
  <div class="slide" id="div1">content 1</div>
  <div class="slide" id="div2">hey I'm content 2</div>
  <div class="slide" id="div3">Now it's content 3</div>
<div>
```

Comment: added close X button

Comment: is there a way that the content on the left moves when the slide show up?

Comment: @KeithMercado could you please explain more your need.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
<div id="rightSideDiv" ></div>
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField1" value="<b> Info of div 1</b>" />
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField2" value="<b> Info of div 2</b>" />
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField3" value="<b> Info of div 3</b>" />

<button onClick="doDisplay('myHiddenField1')">Try it</button>
<button onClick="doDisplay('myHiddenField2')">Try it</button>
<button onClick="doDisplay('myHiddenField3')">Try it</button>

<script>
function doDisplay(hiddenFileldID) {
    var x = document.getElementById(hiddenFileldID).value;
    document.getElementById("rightSideDiv").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: instead of creating so many divisions create hidden fields with different IDs and its value equals to the inner html of those divs. and create only one div for displaying.   OnClick of buttons add respective value of hidden field to inner html of that one div.